# StringBuilder in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm looking for fast string concatenation class or so in Flex. 
Like StringBuilder in Java.

Thanks

Comment: you spelled StringBuilder wrong in the title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var str1:String = "Vinoth";
var str2:String = "Babu";
var str3:String = "Chennai";
var str4:String = concat(str1, " ", str2, " ", str3)
```

trace(str4) would result you 
str4 == "Vinoth babu Chennai"

**String Concat Class**

```
public class StringBuffer
{
    public var buffer:Array = new Array();

    public function add(str:String):void
    {
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            buffer.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
        }
    }

    public function toString():String
    {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(this, buffer);
    }
}
```

Here you have a more indepth than the above class written.

http://blogs.adobe.com/pfarland/2007/10/avoiding_string_concatenation.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of strings and then use `String.concat` to combine them.

However, I've never seen string manipulation come up as a bottleneck when profiling a Flex app.  I have in .NET, but not Flex.

Comment: I ended up creating Array and then used .join() method.