# Why StringBuilder was removed?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My question is simple. Some time ago StringBuilder was removed. What may be the reason of that? How can I deal with large strings now?

Comment: @m.edmondson,The question is on flash not abou .net framework

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`flash.utils.StringBuilder` was first introduced as a response to a lack of performance in `String` concatanation. But then `String` concatanation was optimized so there were no reason to use/keep this `Class`.

Quote from http://onflex.org/ACDS/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf page 38

> For awhile, we had a class flash.utils.StringBuilder for fast string 
>   concatenation  What happened?  A: We made the + operator super-fast
>   by implementing compound strings  (cords), so StringBuilder was
>   unneeded and removed

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting

Comment: The linky no longer works - but I believe here is the same one: http://labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/as3-performance/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for StringBuilder, for if you are using Flex there's the (open source) StringUtil Class. I guess you could use the it as is by copying the source file in your project. I know downloading the whole SDK for one file can be a turn off, but I don't think I can link directly to the file.

You can also check out this related question : [StringBuilder in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815503/stringbuilder-in-flex)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looks like toString() method concats strings contained in buffer. As string is immutable a new string is created in each concatenation. That's not good

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder class was present in early Flash Player 8.5/9 Alphas and Betas, so I don't think they even finished it.

If you are worried about Visible text, you can use TextField.appendText method, which supposed to be optimised String modification method.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#appendText()